# How to add new meta data to alembic file in maya?

Tags: maya, meta, autodesk, alembic-format

I want to add some extra information into the exists abc file or if its possible while creating alembic cache with some extra information in maya or any cg application using pyhon.
I am appreciate any one can help me to edit the alembic file.

input example

```
meta_data = {'name': 'Hero', 'tag': 'test_show'}
abc_file = '/show/test_show/scene/hero.abc'
```

## set meta data ?

```
from alembic import Abc
```

## get meta data

```
from alembic import Abc

archive = Abc.IArchive(abc_file)
top = archive.getTop()
meta_data = top.getMetaData()
print meta_data__str()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't write just arbitrary data but you can set description and application strings:

```py
from alembic import Abc

MY_APP = 'My cool application'


def write(abc_file, description):
    archive = Abc.CreateArchiveWithInfo(abc_file, MY_APP, description) 

def read(abc_file):
    archive = Abc.IArchive(abc_file)
    top = archive.getTop()
    return Abc.GetArchiveInfo(archive)

abc_file = 'alembic.abc'
write(abc_file, 'An abc file cool description')
archive_info = read(abc_file)
print(archive_info.get('appName'))
print(archive_info.get('userDescription'))
print(archive_info.get('whenWritten'))
```

Comment: Doing this completely overwrites the data so that it's an empty cache..

Comment: Of course it does, the sample code creates an empty alembic file. If you want to create a copy of another file you'll need to recursively copy the data. But that's several pages of code.

Comment: So I've posted a full solution as a separate answer

Comment: Great! and Thanks ababak, I will check and let you know my updates.

Comment: _It is working in maya 2017 +, but in maya 2016 Abc.CreateArchiveWithInfo arguments are different. Can you help me the arguments examples._

**Maya 2016 AbcExport v1.0**
**Alembic 1.5.4 (built Jul 11 2014 04:25:46)**

Comment: archive = Abc.CreateArchiveWithInfo(abc_file, MY_APP, description)

Comment: # Error: line 1: Python argument types in
#     alembic.Abc.CreateArchiveWithInfo(str, str, str)
# did not match C++ signature:
#     CreateArchiveWithInfo(std::string fileName, std::string ApplicationWriter, std::string UserDescription, Alembic::Abc::v7::Argument argument, Alembic::Abc::v7::Argument argument)
# Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: @SubinGopi Unfortunately, I can't check this in Maya 2016 but you can try to supply two extra arguments it asks for, maybe `None`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete script that does the job of copying the source alembic file and inserting some metadata:

```py
import os
import alembic


def copy_props(i_props, o_props):
    '''
    Copy properties
    '''
    for index in range(i_props.getNumProperties()):
        header = i_props.getPropertyHeader(index)
        if header.isArray():
            i_prop = alembic.Abc.IArrayProperty(
                i_props,
                header.getName())
            prop_name = i_prop.getName()
            prop_meta = i_prop.getMetaData()
            o_prop = alembic.Abc.OArrayProperty(
                o_props,
                prop_name,
                i_prop.getDataType(),
                prop_meta,
                0)
            o_prop.setTimeSampling(i_prop.getTimeSampling())
            for i in range(i_prop.getNumSamples()):
                o_prop.setValue(i_prop.getValue(i))
        elif header.isScalar():
            i_prop = alembic.Abc.IScalarProperty(
                i_props,
                header.getName())
            prop_name = i_prop.getName()
            prop_meta = i_prop.getMetaData()
            o_prop = alembic.Abc.OScalarProperty(
                o_props,
                prop_name,
                i_prop.getDataType(),
                prop_meta,
                0)
            o_prop.setTimeSampling(i_prop.getTimeSampling())
            for i in range(i_prop.getNumSamples()):
                o_prop.setValue(i_prop.getValue(i))
        elif header.isCompound():
            i_prop = alembic.Abc.ICompoundProperty(
                i_props,
                header.getName())
            prop_name = i_prop.getName()
            prop_meta = i_prop.getMetaData()
            o_prop = alembic.Abc.OCompoundProperty(
                o_props,
                prop_name,
                prop_meta)
            copy_props(i_prop, o_prop)


def copy_object(i_obj, o_obj):
    '''
    Recursively copy object data
    '''
    if o_obj is None:
        return
    i_props = i_obj.getProperties()
    o_props = o_obj.getProperties()
    copy_props(i_props, o_props)
    for index in range(i_obj.getNumChildren()):
        i_child = i_obj.getChild(index)
        i_child_name = i_child.getName()
        i_child_meta = i_child.getMetaData()
        o_child = alembic.Abc.OObject(o_obj, i_child_name, i_child_meta)
        copy_object(i_child, o_child)


def copy_abc(i_path, o_path, app, description):
    '''
    Copy alembic file from i_path to o_path
    '''
    arc_in = alembic.Abc.IArchive(i_path)
    arc_out = alembic.Abc.OArchive(o_path, asOgawa=True)
    arc_out = alembic.Abc.CreateArchiveWithInfo(o_path, app, description)
    top_in = arc_in.getTop()
    top_out = arc_out.getTop()
    copy_object(top_in, top_out)


def read(abc_file):
    archive = alembic.Abc.IArchive(abc_file)
    return alembic.Abc.GetArchiveInfo(archive)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    i_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'itest.abc'
    )
    o_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'otest.abc'
    )
    copy_abc(i_path, o_path, 'Cool app', 'Cool description')
    print('Created archive: ' + o_path)
    archive_info = read(o_path)
    print('App name: ' + archive_info.get('appName'))
    print('Description: ' + archive_info.get('userDescription'))
    print('Written: ' + archive_info.get('whenWritten'))
```

Comment: Great! and Thanks ababak